# Añadir JOIN-ON a un query con la sintaxis de DOCTRINE - DQL

Tags: sql-server, symfony3, symfony, dql

Cuál es la sintaxis para realizar join-on de un objeto de otra entidad con `DQL` asumiendo que el `from`.

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT em
        FROM EmpleadosBundle:Empleados em
        WHERE em.status = :status'
    )->setParameter($status, 1);
```

Comment: Creo que es mejor establecer correctamente las relaciones entre las entidades para que los join te los haga doctrine internamente con el lazy loading y todo eso, aunque no se si esto es suficiente para tu caso.

Comment: Si defines de mejor manera la relación de la base de datos esto es muy sencillo. Puedes poner más información de lo que necesitas conseguir con la consulta a la BDD

Comment: no necesito la consulta como tal @juanitourquiza, lo que necesito es la sintaxis de un join CUALQUIERA ejemplificado en dql

Comment: @juananruiz, ya tengo relacionadas las entidades, pero necesito algunas queries muy especificas para mostrar algunos datos.

Comment: Has visto esto en StackOverflow ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399355/query-builder-dql-not-working-with-inner-join-syntax-issue